# Java - setVisible(false) doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So I just started with JFrame and JMenuBar, and I tried to do this:

main file(the window class is my JFrame class):

```
public class main {
public static void main(String avg[]) {
    window win = new window();
    win.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

my menu class(the Startwin class is another JFrame class):

```
public menu() {
JMenu main = new JMenu("File");                        

JMenuItem start = new JMenuItem("ReStart",KeyEvent.VK_R);      
    start.setActionCommand("press OK to continue");
    start.addActionListener(this);

    JMenuItem save = new JMenuItem("Save",KeyEvent.VK_S);
    save.setActionCommand("saved");
    save.addActionListener(this); 
.
.
.
  main.add(start);                                           
  main.add(save);
.
.
.
.
  @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
window w = new window();
Startwin a = new Startwin();
if (e.getActionCommand()=="press OK to continue") {
    a.setVisible(true);
    w.setVisible(false);
}
}
}
```

So when I ran it, the first JFrame window didn't close.
Any suggestions?

oh and by the way, sorry if the staff I wrote is unreadable...

Comment: Are you sure you have extended JFrame? Can you please provide the full code?

Answer (score 2):

Three things...

### First...

```
window w = new window();
Startwin a = new Startwin();
```

Means you've just created brand new instance of these classes, they have no relationship to any other instances of these classes you have previously created...

### Second...

```
e.getActionCommand()=="press OK to continue"
```

Is not how `String` comparison is done in Java, this is comparing two different memory references, which means they are very unlikely to ever equal, instead, you should consider using something like...

```
"press OK to continue".equals(e.getActionCommand())
```

or

```
"press OK to continue".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())
```

If you want a case insensitive match.

### Third...

Take a look at [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi) and consider using a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) instead...

Comment: The thing is that everything work perfectly except the  w.setVisible(false);